# Where does the tomcat axis file server-config.wsdd come from?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

Part of our system provides a web service through apache tomcat, the service is referenced in the server-config.wsdd file. Unfortunately nobody can remember how it got in there.
The apache set up has changed, and I need to update the system for the new configuration. What magic keywords can I google for to help me work out how and why it got into the existing server-config.wsdd, and how it might fit into the new server-config.wsdd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server-config.wsdd file is generated by the wsdl2java tool from Axis. So, some developer used the tool and copied the file inside your Tomcat conf, where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

The server-config.wsdd is created when you deploy your web service by running

java org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient \deploy.wsdd

Answer (score 1):

my knowledge says that it is hardcoded... and by using java org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient \deploy.wsdd  or by explicitly invoking it through an ant script you can embody it to the server-config.wsdd and deploy the service